# How to set Java JDK path in Android Studio Arctic Fox, Bumblebee, etc.?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox, android-studio-bumblebee

How can I set the new path for Java JDK? I tried to change the environment variables but it did not work.

IDE: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 4

IDE: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`
2. Choose JDK folder for `Gradle JDK` field
3. `Apply`  changes

[image]

NB: If you haven't Java environment on your PC,  go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html and download Java jdk for your platform.

NB2: It's JDK for your Gradle, not for your source code compiler (!)

Comment: This is the Gradle JDK, not the JDK used by the IDE

Comment: @Aliaksei Kisel  In my Arctic Fox I don't have this option, any solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704289/android-studio-arctic-fox-gradle-procject-settings-not-exists

Comment: @babayaro It seems that Gradle wasn't configured for your project. See `Project structure`

Comment: It's always amazing how difficult to find this in the menu, I always need to rely on Stackoverflow to locate it.

Comment: For latest Android Studio (eg: Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1), the `Settings` option can be found by going to
`Android Studio` > `Settings`

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 **Patch 1** has a fix for *"Env variables not sourced when launched from Mac OS X to Monterey Dock"* - See https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/02/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-patch-1.html