# Android studio Arctic Fox gradle procject settings not exists

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need change Java 1.8 to Java 11 or higher but when go to **Settings  > Gradle** don't have Gradle projects options.

I'm open my project in Android Studio but don't have this option.

Any solution how fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These settings are project-specific. You need to have a project opened in your Studio to see the project-specific settings here.

Comment: I'm open project  https://ibb.co/YWcpb2Z

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Gradle wasn't configured for your project. If you want to use Gradle, you can add it first

In other cases see `Project Structure -> Project` settings (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S). You can here change Java version for non-Gradle projects.

Comment: I don't know how configure that this is my screen  https://postimg.cc/4Y8tzj5Q

Comment: push `edit` on this window. Do you see `JDK home path` option?

Comment: When push edit  https://ibb.co/vY8MKMB   Do you need add jdk 17  path in to Enivroment varible in System Propertis

Comment: If it doesn't work, it means that you have another problem that wasn't described in your question.  Probably you have to learn how use gradle on flatter project or something this kind of

Comment: After update gradle from 4 to 7 I'm get this error after run my project in emulator.